useFormStatus resets status.pending too early
I have this form
import { sleepAction } from "@/actions/serveractions";
import SubmitUseFormStatus from "@/components/SubmitButton";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <form action={sleepAction}>
        <SubmitUseFormStatus />{" "}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

and this submit component
"use client";
import { Button } from "@nextui-org/button";
import { Input } from "@nextui-org/input";
import { useFormStatus } from "react-dom";

export default function SubmitUseFormStatus() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 w-48">
      <Input
        name="time"
        type="number"
        placeholder="Time in seconds"
        defaultValue={"4000"}
      />{" "}
      <Button type="submit" color="primary">
        {pending ? "Submitting ..." : "Submit"}
      </Button>{" "}
    </div>
  );
}

sleepAction() is a serveraction that is guaranteed to wait 4000 ms before returning.
"use server";

export async function sleepAction(formData: FormData): Promise<void> {
  const sleeptime = +(formData.get("time") as string);

  console.log(`sleepaction ${sleeptime}`);

  console.log("start ...");
  await sleep(sleeptime);

  console.log("... end");

  return;
}

function sleep(ms: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}


When I hit the submit button, sleepaction is invoked and returns after 4000 ms. useFormStatus returns status.pending = true and after 500ms it returns status.pending = false while sleepaction() is still running. This makes my "Submitting ... / Submit" indicators pretty useless.
What might i have done wrong?
A similar example that uses useActionState() works as expected, so can it be that useFormStatus sets status.pendingto false, as soon as the form is submitted, not waiting for a serveraction response?
